# Bazel and System Environment Variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, environment-variables, bazel

I am building my Java project with Bazel. I want to use environment variables at build/run time. According to the [documentation](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html) `--action_env=APP_ENV=Development` should work.

So I do `bazel run myproject:app --action_env=APP_ENV=Development`

But `System.getenv("APP_ENV");` is null

In my IntelliJ IDE, I have the following. Neither `--action_env=APP_ENV=Development` nor `--action_env APP_ENV=Development` work.

[image: Using IntelliJ]

Did I get something wrong here?

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues might be a better place to ask. Plug-in developer may need to provide the environment variable options to the run configuration like many other configurations in the IDE already do.

Comment: @CrazyCoder But how do i do this on the cli.  `bazel run myproject:app --action_env=APP_ENV=Development` does not work

Answer (score 15):

You can use `--run_under` to add a prefix to the Bazel run command. This can be used in the IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration to set environment variables.

```
--run_under='export VAR1=FOO VAR2=BAR && '
```

Comment: Definitely, the way to go! Thanks.

Comment: It only works in run mode, but not in debug mode. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Launch Intellij from a terminal so it has the environment variables that it needs during bazel sync (build) and bazel run.

On MacOS, use the `open` command to launch it.

```
$ export POSTGRES_USER=dev_user
$ open -a "IntelliJ IDEA CE"
$
```

Bazel will only pass variables to the build processes if you provide them on the command line:

```
$ bazel build --action_env=POSTGRES_USER //...
```

Or specify them in `.bazelrc`:

```
build --action_env=POSTGRES_USER
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the Intellij bazel plugin allows you to specify a bazel binary. You can take advantage of this to add specific environment variables per run configuration.

Let's say you want to add the following to the runtime environment:

```
VAR1=VAL1
VAR2=VAL2
```

Then create a file called say `bazel_custom` with the following contents (replace `/path/to/bazel` with the correct path to bazel):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export VAR1=VAL1
export VAR2=VAL2

/path/to/bazel "$@"
```

Save the file and mark it as executable:
`chmod +x bazel_custom`

Then edit your Intellij bazel run configuration and set the path to the task-specific bazel binary to `/path/to/bazel_custom`.